# Near Lake NFT indexer access is slow

Tags: python, nearprotocol, indexer

We are using near Lake NFT indexer to listen to mainnet block information. We find that it is very slow to obtain data, sometimes in streamer_messages_queue.get() method waits for hundreds of seconds to get the data, and sometimes stops at the streamer_messages_queue.get() method, so we want to know if there is any configuration error or any restriction that causes us to get data very slowly?

```
stream_handle, streamer_messages_queue = streamer(config)
while True:
    start_time = int(time.time())
    logger.info("Start listening time:{}", start_time)
    streamer_message = await streamer_messages_queue.get()
    end_time = int(time.time())
    logger.info("streamer_messages_queue.get() consuming time:{}", start_time - end_time)
    logger.info(f"Block #{streamer_message.block.header.height} Shards: {len(streamer_message.shards)}")
    start_time = int(time.time())
    await handle_streamer_message(streamer_message)
    end_time = int(time.time())
    logger.info("handle_streamer_message consuming time:{}", start_time - end_time)

Output log:
Start listening time:1660711985
streamer_messages_queue.get() consuming time:-282
Block #71516637 Shards: 4
handle_streamer_message consuming time:0
```

When using the method provided by (near_lake_framework) to obtain data, it will wait for a long time at the above code (streamer_messages_queue.get())

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard such reports from people in some regions where AWS S3 is rate-limited. Try using VPN or running it on some server. You could also try Rust or JS versions of near-lake-framework (pick any of [the tutorials](https://near-indexers.io/tutorials/intro)).

Comment: Thanks,We switch the network and try again